# How to import named object in typescript from module

Tags: typescript

If I try something like this:

`export  var common = {}`

then when I import it like this:

`import {common} from "./Common";`

`common` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import * as common from './common'
```

This means import the whole object into the identifier -common-, what your code says is import the property common on the module, and there is no such property.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is the reason I moved away from the default export  was to maintain refactoring capabilities of the named object `{common}`

Comment: `import * as common from './common'` isn't any better to me than just exporting a default object, which is what I reverted back to: `export default  {..`